# SilverStripe: Adding the component to GridField grouping them in a div (toolbar)

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I am adding components to the GridField dynamically. Actually, I am trying to replace the existing components. Since there is no replace method, I have to remove the existing components and add the new components.

Following is my code

```
 $grid = new GridField('ContentBlocks', 'Content Blocks', $this->owner->ContentBlocks(), $editor);
 $grid->getConfig()
      ->removeComponentsByType(GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter::class)
      ->addComponent(new CustomGridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter())
      //configuring other components continue here
```

As you can see in my code, I am removing an existing component and adding a new custom component as a replacement for the one that was removed.

It added the custom component. But there is an issue with that. The issue is that on the front-end, the new component is not added at the exact position as the one that was removed.

See this screenshot:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the search box (the custom component added) went out of the container or div that the add content block button resides in. If I did not do that replacement, they stay in the same row as in the screenshot below.

[image]

What I am thinking is that I am looking for a way to group them back together in one row. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing and adding components of an existing `GridFieldConfig`, we can create our own `GridFieldConfig` and add the components that we want.

```
$contentBlocksFieldConfig = GridFieldConfig::create();
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldButtonRow('before'));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewButton('buttons-before-left'));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new CustomGridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter('buttons-before-right'));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldToolbarHeader());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableHeader());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldFilterHeader());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldDataColumns());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldEditButton());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldDeleteAction(true));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridField_ActionMenu());
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldPageCount('toolbar-header-right'));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldPaginator(25));
$contentBlocksFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldDetailForm());

$contentBlocksField = GridField::create(
    'ContentBlocks', 
    'Content Blocks', 
    $this->ContentBlocks(), 
    $contentBlocksFieldConfig
);
```

The above config component set up is based on the [`GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Forms/GridField/GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor.php) setup. We could use the components of [`GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Forms/GridField/GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor.php) or any of the other configs instead.

Also, to align the Autocompleter to the right we pass `'buttons-before-right'` as a parameter like so:

```
->addComponent(new CustomGridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter('buttons-before-right'))
```

This is assuming `CustomGridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter` has the same constructor as [`GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/src/Forms/GridField/GridFieldAddExistingAutocompleter.php#L93).